# Silverlight 4. How to set a ToolTip with controls in a ResourceDictionary file with Style definitions?

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, styles, tooltip

I've looked at tens of Q&As, but haven't found the answer to this apparently simple need.

I'm working with Silverlight 4. I want to define a ToolTip WITH CONTROLS IN IT at the ResourceDictionary file that has the Style definitions.

My user control file "UC_Activity.xaml" has:

```
...
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource Style0}" Name="tb_id" />
...
```

If my "Styles.xaml" file has

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk">
    <Style x:Key="Style0" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Portable User Interface" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip" Value="Long tooltip text here. This WORKS, but part of the text ends up out of the screen." />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

it works, but I can only show simple text as the ToolTip, and if the text is very long, it will end up out of the screen, where it is impossible to be seen. What I want is something like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk">
    <Style x:Key="Style0" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Portable User Interface" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip">
            <Setter.Value>
                <StackPanel>
                    <sdk:Label Content="Short text here."/>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="200" Text="Long text here. This does NOT WORK." />
                </StackPanel>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

but it does NOT WORK. It builds ok, but it gives an exception ("Value does not fall within the expected range.") when starting execution.

Please, how can I do it?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, the problem is that it needs to be a DataTemplate so a different instance is added to the visual tree every time its used. I created an attached property for this:

then it can just be used as follows:

```
<Setter Property="ControlsBehaviours:TooltipTemplate.Template">
    <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ToolTip Content="tooltip" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

public class TooltipTemplate
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Template Dependency Property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Template",
            typeof (DataTemplate),
            typeof (TooltipTemplate),
            new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(TemplateChanged)));

    public static void SetTemplate(DependencyObject o, DataTemplate value)
    {
        o.SetValue(TemplateProperty, value);
    }

    public static DataTemplate GetTemplate(DependencyObject o)
    {
        return (DataTemplate) o.GetValue(TemplateProperty);
    }

    private static void TemplateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToolTipService.SetToolTip(d, ((DataTemplate)e.NewValue).LoadContent());
    }
}
```